# How to end sentence using implode and array_splice?

Tags: php, html

If we have 5 sentences in our content, and we want to split all text into two areas, we would use soemthing like:

```
$content = 'Sentence number one. Sentence number two. Sentence number 3. Sentence number 4. Sentence number 5.';
$slices = explode(" ", $content);
$first_slice = implode(" ", array_splice($slices, 0, 10));
$second_slice = implode(" ", array_splice($slices, 0));
echo '<div class="first_slice">'. $first_slice .'</div>';
echo '<div class="second_slice">'. $second_slice .'</div>';
```

Output of this is:

```
<div class="first_slice">Sentence number one. Sentence number two. Sentence number 3. Sentence</div>
<div class="second_slice">number 4. Sentence number 5.</div>
```

How to push started sentence to finish?
In this example, how to get output:

```
<div class="first_slice">Sentence number one. Sentence number two. Sentence number 3. Sentence number 4.</div>
<div class="second_slice">Sentence number 5.</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you split into sentences, not words?

Comment: Can you help me how to do it? @Barmar

Comment: There's no excuse for misspelling a name after `@`, since it performs auto-completion.

Comment: Find the second to last occurrence of `. `, then split the string by its index. https://3v4l.org/llnJn splicing and all that is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split in sentences by presuming every sentence end with a point and a blank space.

```
<?php
$content = 'Sentence number one. Sentence number two. Sentence number 3. Sentence number 4. Sentence number 5.';
$sentences = explode(". ", $content);
$first_slice = array_slice($sentences, 0, 3);
$second_slice = array_slice($sentences, 3, 4);
?>
```

And then print the sentences that you want:

```
<div class="first_slice">
<?php
echo implode(" ", $first_slice);
?>
</div>
<div class="second_slice">
<?php
echo implode(" ", $second_slice);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the right start, but you need to add more code to figure out how many sentences to print to get 10 words.

Comment: I need first slice after X sentences, and second slice after first slice is finished.

Comment: @jakobjanda If you need X sentences, use `array_slice($sentences, 0, $x)`

Comment: @jakobjanda Sorry, I didn't get that point. You can do like Barman advises using array_slice to split the sentences array

Comment: I realized how to do it, but if I use array_slice($sentences, 0, 2), it does not take first two sentences in first_slice, but way more like 5-6 sentences.
I'm not sure if this has anything to do with that I am working with wordpress.

Comment: Fixed it by explode only full stop.

Comment: Great! Anyway WordPress has nothing to do with this, you are working with string and PHP functions, not WordPress core functions

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting by spaces, so it will split differently for data sets where the sentences have a variable number of spaces. Something like this will split by punctuation characters, and should work with a wider variety of inputs.

````
$content = 'Sentence number one! Sentence number two. Sentence number 3? 
Sentence number 4. Sentence number 5!';
$slices = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+/', $content, -1);
    
$first_slice = implode(" ", array_splice($slices, 0, 3));
$second_slice = implode(" ", array_splice($slices, 0));
echo '<div class="first_slice">'. $first_slice .'</div>';
echo '<div class="second_slice">'. $second_slice .'</div>';```
````